# Running process under another user in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, session, process

I am trying to launch a process in Windows under specific user account. 
While launching process with `ProcessStartInfo` works locally and when you have the active interactive session. It's not working in remote scenario where the active session is not present.

On Remote machine, `Service ABC` is running under admin account `(domain\adminuser)`, which is launching the `powershell.exe` under same admin account to launch the script and drive the flow.

In the script, I am tried to launch process [non-interactive], but failed to launch the same.

```
$Processinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$Processinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$Processinfo.LoadUserProfile = $false
$Processinfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
$Processinfo.Username = "domain\user"
$Processinfo.PasswordInClearText = "testpass"
$Processinfo.FileName = "abc.exe"
```

I don't see a reason why I am not allowed to launch non-interactive process from Session 0

Comment: How are you invoking remotely ?

Comment: @RanadipDutta, Using the service which is always running in the machine. I do provide the scripts using `Remote-PSSession` to execute

Comment: Please post that too. SO that we can have a look into that also.

Comment: @RanadipDutta, Can you tell me what do you need? As mentioned it just script file that will be passed on to `powershell.exe` from service, which is not in my possesion

Comment: oo so you are basically not invoking remotely. Script is getting executed locally only each time.

Comment: @RanadipDutta yes

Answer (score 0):

To run locally, you can simply use `Start-Process`

```
$Credentials = Get-Credentials
Start-Process -Credential $Credentials -FilePath 'C:\Windows\notepad.exe'
```

For Remote Machine you can use WMI `Create` using the `-List` Parameter:

```
(Get-WmiObject win32_process -ComputerName $computer -Credential $Credentials -List).Create("notepad")
```